# Django add function to button in template

Tags: python, django

I dont know how can I add function from `views.py` to atribute action in my template.
I'd like when I click the button then my page refreshes and add comment to datebase.

Part of my template:

```
    <form action = '???' method = "post">
    {{ formularz.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Part of `views.py`:

```
def ShowNewses(request):
    newses = News.objects.filter(status = 'p')
    return render_to_response('news.html', {'news_set': newses})

def ArchiveNews(request,topic,year, month, day):
    news = News.objects.filter(date__year = int(year), date__month = int(month), date__day = int(day),topic = topic)
    comments = Comments.objects.all()
    formularz = CommentsForm()
    return render_to_response('knews.html', {'news': news[0],'comments': comments, 'formularz': formularz}) 

def AddComment(request):
    L = request.META['PATH_INFO'].split('/')
    if request.POST:    
    k = CommentsForm(request.POST)
    k.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ArchiveNews', kwargs = {'request' = request, 'year' = L[3], 'month' = L[4], 'day' = L[5]}))
```

`AddComment` is function which I want in my button.
`ArchiveNews` is induced when I choose news which will be in new page.

**EDIT**
part of `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^news/$', ShowNewses),
url(r'^news/(?P<topic>.+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})', ArchiveNews),
```

I updated here part of `views.py`. I added `ShowNewses`.

Comment: have you tried named urls and then using ... <form action="{% url myapp_add_comment %}" ... (assuming you name your URL for the AddComment view as myapp_add_comment)

Comment: I tried your way: action = {% url news.views.AddComment %}
If You can please look at my last line in views.py InvalidSyntax but I dont know where

Comment: show us the corresponding lines in your urls.py file.  Also, I don't expect to see dots in the name of the url or "views".

Comment: in your reverse, instead of using kwargs, I think you need to use args=(topic, L[2], L[3], L[4]), but then you also need to make topic equal something ahead of time.

Comment: Your way with args is OK, InvalidSyntax disappears :)
But now, I've problem with TemplaeteSyntaxError, line with {% url ....}

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `AddComment` to your urls.py file. Then, assuming your app is named "myapp" you would use this in your template: `{% url myapp.views.AddComment %}`

Comment: I must to create new rule in urls.py? The same rule like rule for ArchiveNews? I'd like my page refreshs and comment adds to database.

Answer (score 0):

I used url name. My actualy files:
views.py

```
def ArchiveNews(request, topic, year, month, day):
    print request.POST
    news = News.objects.filter(date__year = int(year), date__month = int(month), date__day = int(day),topic = topic)
    comments = Comments.objects.all()
    formularz = CommentsForm()
    return render_to_response('knews.html', {'news': news[0], 'comments': comments, 'formularz': formularz, 'topic': topic, 'year': year, 'month': month,'day': day})   


def AddComment(request,topic,year,month,day):
    print 'foo'
    if request.POST:
        k = CommentsForm(request.POST)
        k.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ArchiveNews', args = (topic,year,month,day)))
```

And part of my template:

```
<form action = {% url addcomment topic year month day %} method = "post">
        {{ formularz.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

part of urls.py:

```
url(r'^news/(?P<topic>.+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})', ArchiveNews),
url(r'^news/(?P<topic>.+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})', AddComment, name = 'addcomment'),
```

EDIT:
I updated my files

Comment: Your url for AddComment is full of parameters, but your AddComment view doesn't accept any.  They need to match.

Comment: I changed it
AddComment(request,topic,year,month,day): ....
but I've got the same error

Comment: Now, if you want to keep all those arguments, then you need to pass them to the template and include them in your {% url ... %} tag

Comment: for example:
{% url addcomment 'a' 2012 06 20 %} Did you think about it?

Comment: include topic, year, month, day in the args in your render_to_response and then in your template, say {% url addcomment topic year, month, day %}.  Also, I think you need double quotes around the {% url ... %} for the sake of the html.

Comment: Thank You, this error disapperas but now when I clicked in button I use ArchiveNews but without AddComment. I used print 'foo' in AddComment for control and i didnt see 'foo' in console

Comment: I don't see a url for AddComment anymore.

Comment: The second url pattern needs to be different than the first one, like url(r'^news/comment/(?P<topic>.+)/ ...